# How do I increase the number of default rows per page?

Tags: grails

Grails scaffolding defaults to 10 rows per page.  I would like to increase that number without generating the views and changing the 10 in every file.  Where do I change the default?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to install scaffold templates with:

grails install-templates

Now, edit in src/templates/scaffolding Controller.groovy and increase the value params.max as you want

Comment: That was my first suggestion, but if you try it you'll see that it only works if you then use the command:  grails generate-* commands, so I removed it.  There is an issue open and I think they may include that in 1.1, I'm hoping anyway:  http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GRAILS-2749

Answer (score 1):

I found this but can't get it to work.  You're supposed to be able (according to [this](http://www.nabble.com/Dynamic-scaffolding-Controller-using-edited-template-td13468221.html)) to scaffold and then override the actions you want (say list) in your controller, but like I said, it doesn't work for me...

```
class PersonController {
  def scaffold = true

  def list = {
    if(!params.max) params.max = 20
    [ personList: Person.list( params ) ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, if you use dynamic scaffolding a workaround for this bug, is edit directly in your GRAILS_HOME/src/grails/templates/scaffolding

Answer (score 0):

Add to the uri:

```
?max=<num_rows_desired>
```

For instance:

```
http://projecthost:8080/Library/Books/list?max=20
```